# Apache DbUtils : Handling multiple result sets returned from Stored Procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, apache-commons-dbutils

I have a problem with using DbUtils to retrieve the results from a Stored Procedure in SQL Server.

The stored procedure when executing in SQL Server Management Studio is returning two separate result sets when executed for a specific input value, but for other values it's returning only one result set. The following images illustrate the issue:

One result set returned:
[image: Results with 1 Table Data]

Two result sets returned:
[image: Result with 2 Table Data]

The problem I am facing here is I am using a DbUtils `BeanListHandler` to convert the results into a list of `UserInfo` beans.

```
List<UserInfo> userList = (List<UserInfo>) run.query(STORED_PROC, new BeanListHandler(UserInfo.class), refId);
```

When the stored procedure returns just one result set it's working fine.
However, in the case where two result sets are returned, it is only giving the list for the first result set.

I think that by using JDBC we can get using multiple `ResultSet` but I am not sure how to handle this DbUtils.

Can somebody provide an insight? If any other info is required, please update me I will provide.

Comment: Can anybody help. Am I not clear regarding my query ?

Comment: can you post the contents of the stored procedure?

Comment: @Dave I am not having access to the query in Stored Proc. I can only execute it to get the results.

Comment: What does the return value @return_value represent (i.e. what is it used to determine...error, returns a specific value that is required elsewhere)?

Comment: The [Javadocs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/apidocs/) for DbUtils don't appear to make any mention of multiple result sets. While it may not be your preferred approach, are you at least able to take advantage of the option to use a JDBC `CallableStatement`, retrieve the various result sets, and build your list of objects that way?

Comment: @Dave That code looks like the boilerplate T-SQL that SQL Server Management Studio generates when you right-click on a stored procedure in the Object Explorer and choose "Execute Stored Procedure...". I obviously have no way of knowing if it really is significant in this particular case, but I sorta doubt it.

Comment: @GordThompson yes I used CallableStatement with Native JDBC and that worked. But that would be a lengthy process and code. Any way to do it in short using Pojo/Beans like UserInfo i am using with DbUtils

Comment: @GordThompson...agreed...as I mentioned below though, and to be honest, having a SP return multiple results is bad form and the ideal solution would be to have a single table result returned as in option 1). I'm a .net guy and never used JDBC and there could be options to deal with multiple recordsets within JDBC but I'm not familiar. Was just responding to the T SQL side.

Comment: Have you considered subclassing `org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner` and overriding the appropriate `.query` method(s) with code that uses `PreparedStatement#getMoreResults()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simple enough to subclass the `QueryRunner` object and then tweak the appropriate `query` method(s) to handle multiple result sets. With the following code I was able to retrieve the full list of `UserInfo` objects using

```java
ResultSetHandler<List<UserInfo>> h = new BeanListHandler<UserInfo>(UserInfo.class);
MyQueryRunner run = new MyQueryRunner(ds);
String sql = 
        "EXEC dbo.Gain_Web_GetCompanyRepByIndRefID @RefID=?";
List<UserInfo> result = run.query(sql, h, 2);
```

where `MyQueryRunner` is

```java
package com.example.so36623732;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner;
import org.apache.commons.dbutils.ResultSetHandler;

public class MyQueryRunner extends QueryRunner {

    public MyQueryRunner(DataSource ds) {
        super(ds);
    }

    /**
     * Executes the given SELECT or EXEC SQL query and returns a result object.
     * The <code>Connection</code> is retrieved from the
     * <code>DataSource</code> set in the constructor.
     * @param <T> The type of object that the handler returns
     * @param sql The SQL statement to execute.
     * @param rsh The handler used to create the result object from
     * the <code>ResultSet</code>.
     * @param params Initialize the PreparedStatement's IN parameters with
     * this array.
     * @return An object generated by the handler.
     * @throws SQLException if a database access error occurs
     */
    public <T> T query(String sql, ResultSetHandler<T> rsh, Object... params) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = this.prepareConnection();

        return this.<T>query(conn, true, sql, rsh, params);
    }

    /**
     * Calls query after checking the parameters to ensure nothing is null.
     * @param conn The connection to use for the query call.
     * @param closeConn True if the connection should be closed, false otherwise.
     * @param sql The SQL statement to execute.
     * @param params An array of query replacement parameters.  Each row in
     * this array is one set of batch replacement values.
     * @return The results of the query.
     * @throws SQLException If there are database or parameter errors.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> T query(Connection conn, boolean closeConn, String sql, ResultSetHandler<T> rsh, Object... params)
            throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Null connection");
        }

        if (sql == null) {
            if (closeConn) {
                close(conn);
            }
            throw new SQLException("Null SQL statement");
        }

        if (rsh == null) {
            if (closeConn) {
                close(conn);
            }
            throw new SQLException("Null ResultSetHandler");
        }

        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        T result = null;
        List<T> allResults = null;

        try {
            stmt = this.prepareStatement(conn, sql);
            this.fillStatement(stmt, params);
            rs = this.wrap(stmt.executeQuery());
            allResults = (List<T>)rsh.handle(rs);
            while (stmt.getMoreResults()) {
                rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                result = rsh.handle(rs);
                allResults.addAll((List<T>)result);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            this.rethrow(e, sql, params);

        } finally {
            try {
                close(rs);
            } finally {
                close(stmt);
                if (closeConn) {
                    close(conn);
                }
            }
        }

        return (T) allResults;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, if that stored procedure is returning 2 result sets in a single execution, you've got bigger problems. Ideally, you want the 2 results to be returned as a single table result from the SP and then you should be ok.

1) Try to contact the person who has access to the SP and bring your case to their attention. Have them create a temp table to store all the records from the 2 results being returned and then just return all the contents in that temp table.

2) If you don't have that option, you can try the process outlined in this article [retrieve-data-from-stored-procedure-which-has-multiple-result-sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082889/retrieve-data-from-stored-procedure-which-has-multiple-result-sets) to get the results if you unable to get any movement from 1)

HTH

Dave

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I tried using native Jdbc and that worked with multiple resultset but that code is lengthy. Is there any way or Api similar to Dbutils we can change that to quick code with Beans/Pojo