# How I can retrieve data from stored procedure in multiple table?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Select
    (@id INT)
AS
    SELECT * FROM EMO;
    SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = @id;
    SELECT * FROM tbl1;

    RETURN 0
```

I am getting data using Entity Framework from that stored procedure using this code:

```
Modalities context = new Modalities();
context.USP_Select(1);
```

How can I define which table data gets in my code?

So here how can I get data different tables in code from the stored procedure?

Comment: Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj691402(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Also, is it your context code first?

Comment: no it is not help. it is database first approach.

Comment: May be you can find a clue from this link : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082889/retrieve-data-from-stored-procedure-which-has-multiple-result-sets#answer-20101750)

Comment: @HumayounKabir it is not help

Comment: @jaipundir but how does it not help? It describes how to map multiple result sets on EF. Did it not work or what?

Answer (score 0):

first, add your stored procedure in .edmx file and create a complex type for that stored procedure and you can use an entity. Use the following link to create complex type

[Adding stored procedures complex types in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833531/adding-stored-procedures-complex-types-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just pass a parameter to select which table you wanna get data from?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_Select
   @table varchar(50),
   @id INT = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN

     IF @table = "EMO" 
     BEGIN 
        SELECT * FROM EMO;
     END
     ELSE IF @table = "student"
     BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = @id;
     END
     ELSE IF @table = "tal1"
     BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tbl1;
     END


END
```