# Receive multiple result sets in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a procedure `Sp1`:

```
Begin
    select product_id, product_name 
    from product

    select dept_id, dept_name 
    from department
end
```

My procedure returns two result sets, now I call to this procedure in another procedure using:

```
exec SP1
```

How can I access the results of `SP1` in this other procedure?

Comment: _"How i **stored result of this SP1 in another procedure**"_ What that mean?  Can't you use a #TempTable? or even better a Function?

Comment: As far as I know, you can only capture the last "result set" from the stored procedure.  As far as I'm concerned, that's a total hack anyway, and you should look into user defined functions or output variables to return values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve data from stored procedure which has multiple result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082889/retrieve-data-from-stored-procedure-which-has-multiple-result-sets)

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to accomplish with the results of those queries?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* get the results from an SP into a table by using the `INSERT INTO..EXEC` syntax. I don't advise it, however, as it relies on **all** datasets being returned from the SP to have the same definition:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE PROC TestProc1 AS

    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'T-Shirt'),
                (2,'Jeans'),
                (3,'Spotlight')) V(ProductID,ProductName);

    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'Clothing'),
                (2,'Lighting')) V(DeptID, DepartmentName);
GO

CREATE TABLE #TempTable (ID int, [Name] varchar(15));

INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC TestProc1;

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable;

GO

DROP TABLE #TempTable
DROP PROC TestProc1;
```

As soon as you throw in a dataset that has a different definition (for example, different number of columns, or perhaps a value that can't be implicitly cast (i.e. 'abc' to an `int`) it'll fail. For example:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE PROC TestProc1 AS

    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'T-Shirt',1),
                (2,'Jeans',1),
                (3,'Spotlight',2)) V(ProductID,ProductName,DeptID);

    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'Clothing'),
                (2,'Lighting')) V(DeptID, DepartmentName);
GO

CREATE TABLE #TempTable (ID int, [Name] varchar(15));

--fails
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC TestProc1;

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable;

GO

DROP TABLE #TempTable;
GO

CREATE TABLE #TempTable (ID int, [Name] varchar(15),OtherID int);

--fails   
INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC TestProc1;

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable;

GO

DROP TABLE #TempTable
DROP PROC TestProc1;
```

You should really be using multiple SP's and handling the data that way.

Comment: The first comment in the first script says fails but I think that should be succeeds.

Comment: I want this multiple result set in another stored procedure not in controller. This two result set come after lot of calculation.

Comment: You're statement be very vague. You can't pass datasets between stored proecures. You could (again) use a temporary table though.